# Is there any way to find how RAM my VPS uses on average?

Tags: linux, process, centos

I have a VPS system with 768MB RAM. Is there any way to find out

- what the average amount of RAM I normally use is
- which processes normally use high RAM and CPU

so that I can see if i need to upgrade it or not?

Answer (score 0):

Just RAM? Not swap?
I have done a dirty scripting job into that:
First we need to parse `ps aux` output for getting mem, command and cpu, thats done in that perl script:

```
@dados = `ps aux`;
for $i ( 0 .. $#dados  ) {
    @l = split('\s+', $dados[$i]);
    $j = join(',',@l[1..9]);
    print "$j,@l[ 10 .. $#l]\n";
}
```

Output will be a comma separated value how will be interpreted by a [Rscript](http://www.r-project.org):

```
efile <- commandArgs(TRUE)
dados <- read.csv(efile[1])
mem<-sum(dados[3])
dados <- dados[order(dados[3],dados[4],decreasing=T),]
sprintf("%f %s",mem,dados[1, 'COMMAND'])
```

This script do the tricky of getting MEM and what command is using more MEM|CPU.

In my *crontab* entry I have the following line.

```
* * * * * perl $HOME/processstats.pl > $HOME/process.csv && Rscript --vanilla $HOME/mstats.R $HOME/process.csv >> $HOME/sysmemcpu.log
```

With R you can make the graphic if needed:

[image: Memory usage]

Sorry if I used a non-standard tool for making the statistics.